# wget cannot change filenames when downloading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dockerfile, command, wget

I'm having a problem downloading a xampp file using wget and choosing to change the filename, but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?

this is command:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2j3s.png)

I tried a few similar articles but it didn't work

Comment: Does it download the file at all? Since the problem looks to be with your download link, not `wget` options. You should use direct download link. Also use `-L` flag if it redirects to another page before download.

Comment: @mokazemi If I remove the link option it downloads normally

Comment: Your question seems to be about _using_ wget, not about _programming_, so it's unsuited to Stack Overflow.  It would be better on [su], but if you post there, please make the question complete, rather than putting the details in an external link.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `wget` to download and then use `mv` to rename it?

```bash
wget http://www.example.com/filename
mv filename installer
```

BTW, in your case, the key issue is that you use the wrong download url. You should use the download url that appeared here:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkwBe.png)

So, it should be as follows in your case:

```bash
wget  https://onboardcloud.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/8.2.12/xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run
mv xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run installer
```

Comment: @conchomauvang I hope my response was helpful in addressing your question. If you find it satisfactory and it resolves your issue, could you please consider accepting it or giving it an upvote? This helps others who might have a similar problem find a solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`wget` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) you instructed `wget` to

> `-o logfile`
> Log all messages to logfile. The messages are normally reported to standard error.

whilst you actually want to

> `-O file`
> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.

i.e. you need to alter `-o` (dash followed by lowercase o) to `-O` (dash followed by uppercase O).